# Django form validation on PIN number

Tags: django

I have a Integerfield in my ModelForm which should contains data between 100000 & 999999. Facing issues in validation. I tried lots of combinations , but doesn't help.

```
from django.forms import ValidationError

class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pin = forms.IntegerField(label="PIN : ", required=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data.get('pin') <= 999999 & self.cleaned_data.get('pin') >= 100000:
            try:
                return int(self.cleaned_data['pin'].strip())
            except ValueError:
                raise ValidationError("Invalid number")
```

My model is as below:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class Company(models.Model):
     comppin = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(100000), MaxValueValidator(999999)])
```

My view is below:

```
def company_form(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if id == 0:
            form = CompanyForm()
        else:
            company = Company.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = CompanyForm(instance = company)
        return render(request, 'company/company_form.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        if id==0:
            form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, f'Company has been created.')
        else:
            company = Company.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = CompanyForm(request.POST, instance=company)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Company has been Updated.')
            #else:
                #messages.alert(request, f'Company has been not Updated.')
        return redirect('company-list')
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong. Need help in this step.

Comment: i am not getting any validation error once I put 0 or blank in the form. I can see that the data is not updating in database. It's okay. But I should get a message in the form that I have put wrong number which is not valid.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, I have updated the view also.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the bitwise-and operator `&` in your clean method. Use `and` or change your if to the following:

```
if 100000 <= self.cleaned_data['pin'] <= 999999:
```

Using `and`:

```
if self.cleaned_data.get('pin') <= 999999 and self.cleaned_data.get('pin') >= 100000:
```

Edit:

Ah, it looks like you're comparing a string to ints. Try the following.

```
def clean(self):
    pin = int(self.cleaned_data['pin'].strip())
    if not( 100000 <= pin <= 999999):
        raise ValidationError("Invalid number")
```

Comment: thanks i have updated the logic. But this doesn't help. I am not getting any validation error still now. Shall I need to update my view?

Comment: @sk.nurujjaman Spotted another problem and updated my answer.

Comment: I have got error while running this code. So changed to below: pin = int(self.cleaned_data['pin'])

Comment: Issue was with views.py. I separated new and edit form. After that form validation is working fine. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with views.py. I separated new and edit form. After that form validation is working fine. Thanks all.